# Scroll View is only rendering Text component and not my own defined component

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Here is the usage for ScrollView Component. The uncommented line works but the commented line does not.
Does ScrollView only render text component?**

```
import { ScrollView,Text ,View} from 'react-native';

import Row from './movies';

export const ScrollViewMovies= (props)=> {

return <ScrollView >{props.movieList.map((movie)=>(<Text key={movie.id}>{movie.movie}</Text> ))}</ScrollView>
// return <ScrollView >{props.movieList.map((movie)=>(<Row movie={movie}/> ))}</ScrollView>

}
```

**Implementation of Row**

```
import React from 'react'
import {TouchableOpacity, Text, View} from 'react-native'


export const Row = (props) => (

     <Text>{props.movie.movie}</Text>


  )
```

**Sample movieList is as follows It has been taken from the OMDB api and I just printed out some of these:**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": 439882,
    "movie": "Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 655926,
    "movie": "Superman Returns",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 727328,
    "movie": "Superman",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 409642,
    "movie": "Superman II",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 83858,
    "movie": "Superman III",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 657398,
    "movie": "Superman IV: The Quest for Peace",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 237090,
    "movie": "Superman/Batman: Apocalypse",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 130426,
    "movie": "Superman/Batman: Public Enemies",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 540753,
    "movie": "Lois & Clark: The New Adventures of Superman",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 443319,
    "movie": "Superman/Doomsday",
  },
]
```

Comment: Please add the sample data of movieList also.

Comment: Please check, I have added the movieList sample as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to use `FlatList` for larger list.

Change your row to :

```
export const Row = (movie) => (
    <Text key={movie.id}>{movie.movie}</Text>
)
```

Comment: Got it, so, even if the props was named props, I could have got it working with props.movie, I was trying to access props.movie.movie which does not make any sense at all.